# Tableau Unexpired Trusted Ticket - including ClientIP

Tags: asp.net, tableau-api

I have an ASP.NET web application in which I'm rendering different tableau dashboards from a site based on the menu clicked by the user. I have multiple menus and each menu was tied to a tableau URL.

Tableau Trusted Authentication has been implemented to get the trusted ticket from the tableau server. Once the ticket has been retrieved, I am appending the ticket to the dashboard URL along with the server name for each menu.

The trusted ticketing module is working fine and the visualizations are getting rendered in my web application. However, frequently I am getting a message of "Could not locate unexpired ticket" error.

On checking with this error, this is due to the ticket calls getting duplicated.

I reached out to the support regarding this and got a response that I can add client_ip during my trusted ticketing.

[Tableau Trusted Ticket](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/Issue/error-could-not-locate-unexpired-trusted-ticket)

I am not able to find any code article related to adding client_ip in trusted ticketing.

Below is my trusted ticket code.

```js
public class TableauTicket
    {
        public string getTableauTicket(string tabserver, string sUsername)
        {
            try
            {
                ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string postData = string.Empty;
                string resString = string.Empty;
 
 
                postData = "username=" + sUsername + "";
 
 
                // FEATURE 816 END - Custom Visualization - KV
                if (postData != string.Empty)
                {
                    byte[] data = enc.GetBytes(postData);
                    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tabserver + "/trusted");
                    req.Method = "POST";
                    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
                    req.ContentLength = data.Length;
 
                    Stream outStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                    outStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    outStream.Close();
 
                    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                    StreamReader inStream = new StreamReader(stream: res.GetResponseStream(), encoding: enc);
                    resString = inStream.ReadToEnd();
                    inStream.Close();
 
                    return resString;
                }
                else
                {
                    resString = "User not authorised";
                    return resString;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string resString = "User not authorised";
                return resString;
                string strTrailDesc = "Exception in tableau ticket - " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        public int Double(int i)
        {
            return i * 2;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know how the client_ip can be passed in trusted ticketing code?

Also, the client IP will get changed for each user and how this will be handled in the trusted ticketing?

**UPDATE**

I have solved the issue using the source code provided by tableau on how to embed the view in SharePoint.

Below is the code which may help users having the same issue.

```
string GetTableauTicket(string tabserver, string tabuser, ref string errMsg)
        {
            ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
            // the client_ip parameter isn't necessary to send in the POST unless you have
            // wgserver.extended_trusted_ip_checking enabled (it's disabled by default)
            string postData = "username=" + tabuser + "&client_ip=" + Page.Request.UserHostAddress;
            byte[] data = enc.GetBytes(postData);

            try
            {
                string http = _tabssl ? "https://" : "http://";

                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http + tabserver + "/trusted");

                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.ContentLength = data.Length;

                // Write the request
                Stream outStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                outStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                outStream.Close();

                // Do the request to get the response
                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                StreamReader inStream = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), enc);
                string resString = inStream.ReadToEnd();
                inStream.Close();

                return resString;
            }
            // if anything bad happens, copy the error string out and return a "-1" to indicate failure
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errMsg = ex.ToString();
                return "-1";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is working, (I have done this part in Java and not really an expert in asp.net) all you have to do is to add something like:

```
postData = postData +"&client_ip=" +<variable for client IP>;
```

The way it is handled on tableau server is :

1. you turn on wgserver.extended_trusted_ip_checking on Tableau server. [see details here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_optional.htm)
2. Tableau will match the client IP you passed in the POST request 'client_ip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' while obtaining the token, with the actual IP of the the machine where the browser is trying to access tableau server.

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried this one and implemented the solution. Tableau had examples of how to embed the view in SharePoint and it has full source code. It helped me to solve my issue.